# Error al cambiar de versión de php con Laragon en windows 10

Tags: php, laragon

a mi me arroja el siguiente error con windows 10 cuando cambio en laragon la versión de php 8.1 a las 8.2. no he logrado solucionarlo.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Aparentemente la versión de curl esta buscando nghttp2 pero no existe en tu sistema. Puedes leer este post: https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/12491

Answer (score 0):

tienes que actaulizar Apache para solucionar ese error, comparto el enlace para que descargues el paquete según tu SO. En laragon solo tiene que descargar el zip en la carpeta de **`laragon/bin/apache`** y descomprimir para que funcione. Luego dentro de Laragon le cambias la version a usar y reinicias los servicios. Es mi primer ayuda y espero que te sirva.